# Compare Dates Pipe Angular 6 - How get Data from Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, compare

I use Angular CLI6

What is wrong ?

I want to hide DateEnd if the month and the year is equal to the month and year of the start date?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
<mat-list *ngIf="!SameDates()">({{ ppsToDisplay?.EndDate | date:'MMMM y'}}) </mat-list>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
```

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe)

```
SameDates(): boolean {
   return datePipe.transform(this.StartDate, 'MM-yyyy') === 
            datePipe.transform(this.EndDate, 'MM-yyyy');
}
```

All my dateend are hidden ....

I obtain my data like this :

Service :

```
return this.database.list('/ppss', ref => ref.orderByChild("Patientid").equalTo(Patientid)).valueChanges();
}
```

Component :

```
this.route.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
   this.patientid = urlParameters['id'];});
this.ppssToDisplay = this.ppssService.getPPSByPatientid(this.patientid);
```

Comment: I think you should console datePipe.transform(this.StartDate, 'MM-yyyy') and datePipe.transform(this.EndDate, 'MM-yyyy'). Also you should check if this.StartDate and this.EndDate is coming as expected.

Comment: For one, you spelled the function once as `sameDates` and once as `SameDates`.